# How to handle wcf error when server is down?

Tags: c#, wcf, exception

I added a WCF service using add service reference feature. WCF is hosted in IIS. When I stop IIS(or suppose server is shut down)and I am making a WCF call it shows error "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found." in catch block. How could I show a message like - "Server is down." or something like that. I am using `"basicHttpBinding"`. Is there any way to catch this type of error like we can catch in - `DivideByZeroException`?

Comment: 1. Expect the tyep of the thrown exception. 2. Add a try-catch where you catch that specific exception. 3. Show a message.

Comment: The expected exception type is very likely ´EndpointNotFoundException´.